# Transaction pending in Remix IDE when trying to pass an array

Tags: solidity, remix, arrays, pending-transactions

This is the contract I have tried to implement.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract Vaccination {
    uint[] public lengths;
    function getSize(uint[] memory arr) public returns(uint){
        lengths.push(arr.length);
        return arr.length;
    }
    
}
```

It compiles just fine but when I try to pass an array from Remix IDE as [1,2], it gets stuck on `transact to Test.getSize pending ...` .

However, when I change the code to:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract Test {
    function getSize(uint[] memory arr) public pure returns(uint){
        return arr.length;
    }
    
}
```

it works just fine.